# Use Azure Notification Hubs REST API to read all registrations of a channel

Tags: azure-notificationhub

The **`Azure Notification Hubs REST API`** documentation for "[Read All Registrations of a Channel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn223271.aspx)" states to use following request URI (e.g. for Apple Push Notification Service device tokens), which doesn't work: `https://{namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{NotificationHub}/registrations/?$filter=DeviceToken eq ‘{deviceToken}’&api-version=2013-08`

I always get the HTTP response code `400` (*Bad Request. Notification hubs do not support this query*).

Even more confusing, the [german version of the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/azure/dn223271.aspx) uses double quotes, which doesn't work either and gives me the same response code: `https://{Namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{Benachrichtigungshub}/registrations/?$filter=DeviceToken eq "{Gerätetoken}"&api-version=2013-08`

**What is the correct format for requesting all Azure Notification Hubs registrations of a channel using the REST API?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The request URI must be in this format: `https://{namespace}.servicebus.windows.net/{NotificationHub}/registrations/?$filter=DeviceToken+eq+'{deviceToken}'&api-version=2013-08`

- `+` instead of spaces (actually URL encoding the spaces (`%20`) will also work)
- `''` (apostrophe / straight single quote - U+0027) instead of `‘’` (single curved quotation marks - U+2018 and U+2019) or `""` (straight double quote - U+0022)

Example: `https://myServiceBusNamespace.servicebus.windows.net/myHub/registrations/?$filter=DeviceToken+eq+'2ED202AC08EA9033665E853A3DC8BC4C5E78F7A6CF8D55910DF230567037DCC4'&api-version=2013-08`